# Send a MediaStream (MediaDevices) to another page

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, navigator, mediastream

**Hello**

I have two pages with different domains

i'm using "puppeteer" package to make a fake media stream stream

1 - The first page is sharing the fake mediaStream

2 - On the second page, I have a video player

I want to send the video from the second page to the first page and replace the fake MediaStream with the "new video"

for example :

```js
const stream = document.querySelector("#video");
const abc = stream.captureStream(60);

var option = {video: {mediaSource: 'screen'}};
let streamm = navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia = (option) => Promise.resolve(abc)
```

This is what I do if the video is on the same page, but I didn't find any way to take the video from another page

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.